# If leakage current for a diode is 20μA at 20 degrees celsius, what is its value at 40 degrees celsius?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, temperature, semiconductor-physics

I'm not sure how to go about this question as these are the only values provided.
How do I find the relationship between Io and VT?

Answer (score 2):

For an ideal diode

$$i = i_0 [exp(\frac{qV}{kT}) -1]$$

where $i$ is the net current flowing through the diode,
$i_0$ is the "dark saturation current" (diode leakage current density in the absence of light), $V$ is the applied voltage across the terminals of the diode, $q$ is the electron charge, $k$ is the Boltzmann constant and $T$ is the absolute temperature (in Kelvin).

And for a non-ideal (real) diode

$$i = i_0 [exp(\frac{qV}{nkT}) -1]$$

where $n$ is the ideality factor. This should be enough information for you to be able to determine $i_0$. It is assumed that the values for the other quantities above have been given to you.

Comment: Nope, the other values have not been given. So do I substitute them with random values?